# Align CSS Arrow

Tags: html, css

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fyGp/)

I did try to align the green arrow in the middle of the `a` but I am not able to do so. I did try `margin-left` with `%` with always off.

Anyone can help please ? Getting tired.

Thanks.

Comment: You can add a div in your `<li>` to put it below&middle. [example](http://jsfiddle.net/2fyGp/5/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that your arrows are absolute positioned, but not relative to the a.

Make following changes to your css and it works

```
.container-menu nav ul li.active a,
.container-menu nav ul li a:hover{
    color: #8fb63a;
    text-decoration: none;
    position:relative;
}

.container-menu nav ul li.active a::after{
    border-bottom: 6px solid #8fb63a;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 0;
    margin-top: 34px;
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 0;
    left:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are over complicating the problem.

Your HTML and CSS need to follow standard formatting in div alignment to really do this the right way.

This fiddle should get you started:

http://jsfiddle.net/2fyGp/4/
*No Formatting*
http://jsfiddle.net/2fyGp/6/
*Some Formatting*

---

```
<style>
.x0 {width:100%;float:left;background-color:#333;border-bottom:2px solid #8FB63A;}
.x0 div{width:25%;float:left;text-align:center;}
.x0 div:hover {color:#8FB63A;}
.x1 div{width:100%;float:left;color:#fff;}
</style>

<div class="x0">
    <div class="x1">
        <div>
            one
        </div>
        <div>
            arrow
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="x1">
        <div>
            two
        </div>
        <div>
            arrow
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="x1">
        <div>
            three
        </div>
        <div>
            arrow
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="x1">
        <div>
            four
        </div>
        <div>
            arrow
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```